# Play Framework logback.xml does not adhere to env variable provided

Tags: logging, configuration, logback, playframework-2.3

I have a custom `conf/logback.xml` which looks like so:

```
<configuration>

  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
     <file>${application.home}/logs/application.log</file>
     <encoder>
       <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
     </encoder>
   </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date - %coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{5}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="my-app" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
     <file>${application.home}/logs/my-app.log</file>
     <encoder>
       <pattern>%date - [%logger] [%level] - %message%n</pattern>
     </encoder>
  </appender>

</configuration>
```

when I stage my app `activator clean stage` and go to `target/universal/stage/bin` and execute `./myApp -Dapplication.home=/home/me/myApp` I expect the logs to be created and written to `/home/me/myApp/logs` but instead what I see is :

1. directory is created in `/home/me/myApp/logs` with empty log files
2. directory is also created in `/home/me/myApp/target/universal/stage/logs` with log files [not expected]
3. all user action in the app is causing the logs to be written to `target/universal/stage/logs` instead of what I defined as `${application.home}` [not expected]

when I ran `./myApp -verbose -Dapplication.home=/home/me/myApp` I saw there was a parameter being printed :
`-Duser.dir=/home/me/myApp/target/universal/stage` which leads me to believe this is affecting where the logs are eventually being written.

Any ideas why logback is not writing to the new files created in `/home/me/myApp/logs` but instead creates `/home/me/myApp/target/universal/stage/logs` and writes all logs there?

Thanks.